# Ruby refinements with instance_eval

Tags: ruby, instance-eval, refinements

I'd like to provide some refinements to a DSL. I'm able to get refinements working with this example:

```
module ArrayExtras
  refine Array do
    def speak
      puts 'array!'
    end
  end
end

module MyUniverse
  using ArrayExtras
  class Thing
    def initialize
      [1].speak
    end
  end
end
MyUniverse::Thing.new
```

This prints out "array!" just fine. But once I introduce `instance_eval`, the method can't be found:

```
module MyUniverse
  using ArrayExtras
  class DSL
    def initialize(&block)
      instance_eval(&block)
    end
  end
end

MyUniverse::DSL.new do
  [1].speak
end
```

I get a `undefined method`speak' for [1]:Array (NoMethodError)`

Is there a way to get refinements working within an instance_eval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refinements are lexically scoped. You are activating the Refinement in the wrong lexical context. You need to activate it where you are calling the refined method:

```
module ArrayExtras
  refine Array do
    def speak
      puts 'array!'
    end
  end
end

module MyUniverse
  class DSL
    def initialize(&block)
      instance_eval(&block)
    end
  end
end

using ArrayExtras

MyUniverse::DSL.new do
  [1].speak
end
# array!
```

Comment: So there is no way to make `MyUniverse::DSL.new` method call self-contained? I.e. to not require users of this method to add `using ...` line to their code.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you can achieve it by `using ArrayExtras`  on the binding.

```rb
module MyUniverse
  using ArrayExtras
  class DSL
    def initialize(&block)
      block.binding.eval("using ArrayExtras")
      instance_eval(&block)
    end
  end
end

MyUniverse::DSL.new do
  [1].speak
end
```

This will however only work if you are not using your class in an instance, it only works if the `binding` is a module or class context, otherwise the `eval` will fail because `main.using is permitted only at toplevel` .

Answer (score -1):

If you want to refine the ruby core `BaseObject`, you need to modify it as below.

```
module ArrayExtras
  refine ::Array do
    def speak
      puts 'array!'
   end
  end
end
```

It will be found in top level class.